# Spark - Scala - Join RDDS (csv) files

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I'm coming in and learning scala, as I am in the initial steps, appeared a demand and need to know how to join in two fields like a relational database.

Example:

> Table 1 ( csv )
>
> zip_type,   primary_city,   acceptable_cities,  unacceptable_cities

Example:

> Table 2 ( csv )
>
> GEO.id, GEO.id2,    GEO.display-label,  VD01

Question:

I want to join Column1 (zip type)Table1 with Column2(GEO.id2)Table2.

Currently I:

- Created an RDD with my CSV file
- Processed each line using the CSV parser but I have a little trouble to making the join.

What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make join you need pair-rdds with same key column. 
Consider transforming RDD-1 into RDD of tuple (K, V) with zip-type as key, similarly RDD-2 with GEO.id2 as key.